# Determining all scalars $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which a matrixrepresentation is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

**Problem:** Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and \begin{align*} T: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}: A \mapsto aA. \end{align*} Determine all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis is an orthogonal matrix.

I have no idea how to do this. I know that $A^T = A^{-1}$ or $A^T \cdot A = I_n$ for an orthogonal matrix, but how can I use this here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** The matrix associated to $T$ is $a$ times the identity matrix $I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix acting on $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$.

Comment: So you mean I need to find all scalars $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the transpose of a scalar matrix equals its own inverse?

Comment: @Kamil No, what I mean is the following: you can see the vector space $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ as $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ (these space have same finite dimension and thus are isomorphic). With this view, the matrix of $T$ is simply $aI_{n^2}$. Now, you have to determine $a$ for which $aI_{n^2}$ is orthogonal, can you go from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** And orthogonal transform maps unit vectors to unit vectors